# Do I need to add some locks or synchronization if there is only one thread writing and several threads reading?

Tags: java, multithreading, locking, synchronized

Say I have a global object:

```
class Global {
   public static int remoteNumber = 0;
}
```

There is a thread runs periodically to get new number from remote, and updates it (only write):

```
new Thread {
   @override
   public void run() {
       while(true) {
           int newNumber = getFromRemote();
           Global.remoteNumber = newNumber;
           Thread.sleep(1000);
       }
   }
}
```

And there are one or more threads using this global `remoteNumber` randomly (only read):

```
int n = Global.remoteNumber;
doSomethingWith(n);
```

You can see I don't use any locks or `synchronize` to protected it, is it correct? Is there any potential issue that might cause problems?

---

Update:

In my case, it's not really important that the reading threads must get the latest new value in realtime. I mean, if there is any issue (caused of lacking lock/synchronization) make one reading thread  missed that value, it doesn't matter, because it will have chance to run the same code soon (maybe in a loop)

But reading a undetermined value is not allowed (I mean, if the old value is 20, the new updated value is 30, but the reading threads reads a non-existent value say 33, I'm not sure if it's possible)

Comment: Yes, one thread writing and several threads reading is *exactly* the case where you need synchronization.

Comment: For that usecase specifically, you'll have visibility issues: the reading thread might not see the new value of the global number. You at least need to make it volatile, or better, to use an AtomicInteger.

Comment: The reading threads might **never** see the new value. Why use incorrect code rather than correct code, especially when all you need to make it correct is to use an AtomicInteger or a volatile int? Do you really think that will cause any performance problem? It won't.

Comment: @JBNizet, thanks, I just don't understand why we should use these protections and not just want to copy that patterns blindly. But thanks for the great answers, now I get much clearer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need synchronization here (with one caveat, which I'll discuss later).

The main problem is that the reader threads may never see any of the updates the writer thread makes.  Usually any given write will be seen eventually.  But here your update loop is so simple that a write could easily be held in cache and never make it out to main memory.  So you really must synchronize here.

**EDIT 11/2017** I'm going to update this and say that it's probably not realistic that a value could be held in cache for so long.  I think it's a issue though that a variable access like this could be optimized by the compiler and held in a register though.  So synchronization is still needed (or `volatile`) to tell the optimizer to be sure to actually fetch a new value for each loop.

So you either need to use `volatile`, or you need to use a (static) getter and setter methods, and you need to use the `synchronized` keyword on both methods.  For an occasional write like this, the `volatile` keyword is **much** lighter weight.

The caveat is if you truly don't need to see timely updates from the write thread, you don't have to synchronize.  If a indefinite delay won't affect your program functionality, you could skip the synchronization.  But something like this on a timer doesn't look like a good use case for omitting synchronization.

EDIT: Per Brian Goetz in *Java Concurrency in Practice*, it is not allowed for Java/a JVM to show you "indeterminate" values -- values that were never written.  Those are more technically called "out of thin air" values and they are disallowed by the Java spec.  You are guaranteed to see some write that was previously made to your global variable, either the zero it was initialized with, or some subsequent write, but no other values are permitted.

Comment: I wonder is there any running example can demonstrate this problem without `volatile` or `synchronization`?

Comment: If you have more than a couple cores, I think you could do it.  With only a few cores, processes will be swapped enough that I don't think you would notice a lag in updates.  But if you had more cores I think the writer thread could actually stay on a single CPU long enough to have a noticeable effect.

Comment: Hmm, if you have one volatile and one non-volatile field, you might be able to demonstrate it, but you'll have to be careful: synchronization actually updates *ALL* writes in Java, so a write to a volatile field will update other non-volatile fields.  (Synchronization in Java is basically a memory fence, if you know what that is.  A machine instruction to flush cache, which updates all writes.)

Comment: Illustrating it is quite simple: start a thread that waits for a non-volatile boolean to become false to stop. Change that other variable in another thread, and watch your program never stop. Regarding out-of-thin-air values, beware though: if you change the int to a long, and don't make it volatile or synchronized, you might see a long value that has never been assigned, simply because the assignment is not necessarily atomic: it can assign the 4 first bytes, and then the 4 next ones. Once again, a volatile or (preferrably, IMO) an AtomicLong makes sure that doesn't happen.

Comment: @JBNizet no that is not true. Start a thread that waits for a non-volatile boolean to become false to stop and it will stop immediatly. Java has become a lot better with that stuff. In pratice you will have no problems if you don't sync if one thread is writing and multiple reading. Volatile is of course the cleaner way though.

Comment: @DominikK that's completely incorrect. The spec clearly says that there is no visibility guarantee, and in practice, there is indeed no guarantee at all. If there was such a guarantee, Java would not be better: it would be worse because it would become much slower. Just execute https://gist.github.com/jnizet/a5437c4c3bb85108b1261298c2bcbf0b with and without volatile, and see the difference.

Comment: @DominikK I have to agree with JB here.  In my experience, if you access a single non-volatile variable in a loop (like testing it constantly for a change) Java will definitely hoist that value into a register and never let it go.  In this case it's a code optimization, but it could be memory visibility issues.  Realistically, many of those visibility issues don't occur because modern CPUs make better memory visibility guarantees, but back in the old days (1995) those CPUs were not common, so Java is designed so it can run on simpler hardware if needed.  It's a good thing imo, esp. with IOT.

Answer (score 3):

Read threads can read old value for undetermined time, but in practice there no problem. Its because each thread has own copy of this variable. Sometimes they sync. You can use volatile keyword to remove this optimisation:

```
public static volatile int remoteNumber = 0;
```