# Java: Is this approach thread safe?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a Thread and I need to set when it is listening or in standby, for that I've defined

```
public static enum ListenerState { STAND_BY, LISTENING };
```

and a method

```
public void setState(ListenerState state){
    this.state = state;
}
```

now, in the main loop I check the state in this way

```
@Override
public void run() {
    while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
        try {
            if (state==ListenerState.LISTENING){
               // do my job
            }
            else{
                Thread.sleep(300);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is this approach thread-safe ?

Comment: Related:  [This example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.3) in the Java Language Specification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, do like that:

```
class MyThread implements Runnable {

    private volatile ListenerState state;

    public synchronized void setState(ListenerState state){
       this.state = state;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
       while (true) {
         try {
            if (state==ListenerState.LISTENING){
              // do my job
            } else{
              Thread.sleep(300);
            }
          } catch (IterruptedException ex){
            return; 
          }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can find your answer here: [Do I need to add some locks or synchronization if there is only one thread writing and several threads reading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27120914/do-i-need-to-add-some-locks-or-synchronization-if-there-is-only-one-thread-writi)

in one word: better to add `volatile` keyword to state.

Answer (score 1):

if state can be changed or read by different thread, then you need to synronize block for reading and writing methods. or as a better way, use `AtomicBoolean`. it is perfect object to get rid of syncronize block and make it thread safe

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicBoolean.html