# Does a non-volatile variable need synchronized?

Tags: java, concurrency, synchronized

Consider 2 threads and an array `int[] values`.
The first thread is performing:

```
synchronized (values) {
     values[i] = 58;
}
```

while the second thread is performing:

```
if (values[i] == 58) {
}
```

outside a `synchronized` block.

If the first thread first performs `values[i]= 58`, is it guaranteed that if the second threads executes slightly later, that the `if` of the second thread reads `58` even though the second thread reads `values[i]` outside a `synchronized` block?

Comment: How do you even ensure that "the second threads executes slightly later"?

Comment: It definitely is not guaranteed. See the Java Language Specification, [section 17.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.3).

Comment: You seem to be asking if Java requires `sychronized` on both reads and writes, or if it's only required on the write.  That question has already been answered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27120914/do-i-need-to-add-some-locks-or-synchronization-if-there-is-only-one-thread-writi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aforementioned behavior is not guaranteed. The guarantee of such a "visibility" is actually a subject of **happens-before relationship**:

> The key to avoiding memory consistency errors is understanding the [happens-before relationship](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/memconsist.html). This relationship is simply a guarantee that memory writes by one specific statement are visible to another specific statement.

Happens-before relationship ([according to JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html#MemoryVisibility)) can be achieved as such:

1. Each action in a thread happens-before every action in that thread that comes later in the program's order.
2. An unlock (synchronized block or method exit) of a monitor happens-before every subsequent lock (synchronized block or method entry) of that same monitor. And because the happens-before relation is transitive, all actions of a thread prior to unlocking happen-before all actions subsequent to any thread locking that monitor.
3. A write to a volatile field happens-before every subsequent read of that same field. Writes and reads of volatile fields have similar memory consistency effects as entering and exiting monitors, but do not entail mutual exclusion locking.
4. A call to start on a thread happens-before any action in the started thread.
5. All actions in a thread happen-before any other thread successfully returns from a join on that thread.

So, in your particular case, you actually need either synchronization using a shared monitor or [AtomicIntegerArray](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicIntegerArray.html) in order to make access to the array thread-safe; `volatile` modifier won't help as is, because it only affects the variable pointing to the array, not the array's elements ([more detailed explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5173642/7884542)).

Answer (score 2):

> If the first thread first performs values[i]= 58, is it guaranteed
>   that if the second threads executes slightly later, that the if of the
>   second thread reads 58 even though the second thread reads values[i]
>   outside a synchronized block?

No

Synchronising this way does not stop other threads to perform any operation on the array simultaneously. However, other threads will be prevented to grab a lock on the array.